# AMPPS Domain Panel Adding Domain Name Error

Tags: php, apache, ssl, ampps, addon-domain

Stuck with 3.8 MySQL connection denied, Uninstalled and Reinstalled with AMPPS 3.9 in Win10 x64
[AMPPS Local Host Config Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhx5q.jpg)

However Trying to Add Domain 'https://example.com' in the localhost thru AMPPS Panel returned message 'Error'. Besides the 'Error', the loading icon continuously rotating

Neither added the entry in domain panel nor in the Entries of host file  AMPPS. Even the Windows host file failed to add the domain. We have cross checked reported error that failed in rewriting the added domain

#### localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself. Domain name 'example.com' added manually in host file as it was failed at AMPPS Domain Panel

The host file config

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
::1          localhost
127.0.0.1    example.com ### added manually
```

As the host file failed to rewrite the config  we added the example.com and tried the same but failed to populate the project

However we checked the AMPPS root/www and  found the domain 'www / example.com' has been added with the above error.

But the installed project url did not work although when you successfully installed the app thru installer.

Next we installed the project at Administrative URL : 'https://example.com/extplorer/index.php' softaculous in AMPPS successfully, but the link reported error.

## Error Example Domain

### This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.

This was not the case in AMPPS 3.8 which were added and deleted the domain without issue. The only issue we had to face due to AMPPS 3.8 that it landed up in the PHPmyAdmin failed to connect with same password 'msyql ' in my.conf but phpmyadmin did not accept and frustrated until a week we just uninstalled AMPPS 3.8 (lost to projects) due to frequent issue with phpmyadmin 1045 Access Denied Error

and then we installed AMPPS 3.9 x64 bit (but installed as x32)

But Ampps 3.9 of domain addon has continued this issue even after three times.clean reinstall

> We have checked the config having following config in E:\Ampps\conf\httpd.conf

```
ServerName 127.0.0.1:80
DocumentRoot "{$path}/www"

Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Again the same Directory config repeated with different params against above which seems to be conflict

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
LogLevel warn
```

Localhost VirtualHost

```
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
allow from All
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost 127.0.0.1
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "{$path}/www/cgi-bin/"
DocumentRoot "{$path}/www"
ErrorLog "{$path}/apache/logs/error.log"
CustomLog "{$path}/apache/logs/access.log" combined
```

## Secure (SSL/TLS) connections

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
Include conf/extra/alias.conf
```

## Virtual hosts

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
```

> We have checked the virtual host config having following config at E:\Ampps\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

DO NOT EDIT, CREATED BY AMPPS

example.com VirtualHost

```
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
allow from All

ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example.com
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "E:/Ampps/www/example.com/cgi-bin/"
DocumentRoot "E:/Ampps/www/example.com"
ErrorLog "E:/Ampps/apache/logs/example.com.err"
CustomLog "E:/Ampps/apache/logs/example.com.log" combined
```

#

example.com SSL Entries

```
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
allow from All

ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example.com
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "E:/Ampps/www/example.com/cgi-bin/"
DocumentRoot "E:/Ampps/www/example.com"
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile "E:\Ampps/apache/conf/ssl_crt/example.com.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "E:\Ampps/apache/conf/ssl_key/example.com.key"
ErrorLog "E:/Ampps/apache/logs/example.com_ssl_error.log"
TransferLog "E:/Ampps/apache/logs/example.com_ssl_access.log"
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars

BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
CustomLog "E:/Ampps/apache/logs/example.com_ssl_request.log" \
"%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
```

#

Your kindness will be highly regarded for providing valuable feedback for solution